Unwanted polygon-snippets after using the difference-tool with a traced polygon
On the picture below, my original polygon is purple (line filled)
I created the grey polygons using the trace tool along the outline of the purple polygon.
When applying the difference-tool, the blue polygon gets created. It has several snippets, where apparently the trace-tool did not create the very same vertex-position.
The purple layer was originally delivered in a FileGDB. I exported it to a GPKG and am using only the GPKG version for digitizing. This layer must not be modified.
The goal of my project is to deliver the grey polygons as precise as possible. If this is not possible, at least the blue layer should be without the resulting snippets.
How can I reach my goal?
I use QGIS version 3.36.2-Maidenhead. In layer properties – digitizing – geometry precision, there is no precision restriction set. There is no offset set for the trace tool (0.000000). Topological editing is off.
I turned the topological editing off, because it causes some other precision problems (see my question Polygon precision problem in QGIS)

I also tested the SAGA difference tool instead of the native QGIS one. It creates a different result. All the snippets in the image above are not shown. But in other part of the polygon it looks like this:
QGIS difference tool:

SAGA difference tool


I found a way to fix the grey polygons partially:
Blue layer to singelparts -> select only the small snippets -> union with the grey polygons -> dissolve -> to singleparts -> add attributes by location. Now it's fixed, and a new difference with the purple layer can be made.
I still don't know how to fix the snippets, which are attached to the blue polygon (1st picture top left).
Also it doesn't help me to understand, why the trace tool doesn't trace exactly.

Buffer with a small negative distance, buffer the output with the same but positive distance

@Bera: This will cause the edges to be unprecise (at a very small scale, but I need it very precise)

Buffer the grey polygons, remove the parts overlapping the purple. Difference the purple with the output

Thanks a lot @Bera. I did as you said plus difference with the grey polygons as well (which is the same as differencing the blue with the output). This lets me fix the blue layer.
Still, I’d really like to create very precise polygons when using the trace tool. Does anyone know what I can do? My goal is to have a very precise blue and grey layer.

To fix my grey polygons I thought, I might take the unfixed blue layer, difference with the fixed blue layer and union those polygon-parts with the grey layer. Surprisingly, differencing the old and new blue layer creates new snippets where there was nothing removed before with the grey layer. This makes me think that maybe not the tracing is the problem, but the difference tool? This theory would be supported by the fact that QGIS’s and SAGA’s difference output are not the same.

I just asked a friend to do a “erase” and “pairwise erase” with ArcGIS pro on the same data, which I exported to a FileGDB first. The output was perfect as it should be. What is the difference between ArcGIS “erase” and QGIS difference? And how can I do the job with QGIS? Can I now assume, that my grey layer is precise?

Have you tried the same operations on an earlier version of QGIS such as 3.16?

@Kartograaf I just downloaded 3.16.0-Hannover and executed the dissolve. Same result.
